# Umbraco: URL re-writer

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I have a website developed in Umbraco CMS, I would like to re-write old website links like

http://www.mywebsite.com/about/default.htm

to

http://www.mywebsite.com/about/overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the urlrewriting.config file that's included in the "/config" folder of the site. You'll need to add a rule, something like this:

```
<add name="[PUT A UNIQUE NAME HERE]"
  virtualUrl="^~/about/default\.htm$"
  rewriteUrlParameter="IncludeQueryStringForRewrite"
  destinationUrl="~/about/overview" redirect="Application"
  ignoreCase="true"  redirectMode="Permanent"/>
```

If you are running IIS7+ it should work straight away, but on older versions of IIS you'll need to to map the .htm extension to run through the asp.net DLL for it to be picked up correctly.